# JSX element disappears after update using useState() hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently having an issue with my ReactJS code. I am writing a browser and I get the URL input by using useState(), when a user has entered the URL it will replace 'url' with the URL that was entered earlier. I thought everything would work fine but it removed the 'active' class that was used to display the content when I tried it.

I have spent hours on this problem but can't even though this one is very simple. Any solutions would be appreciated.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../../components/utils/window/Window.scss';
import TopBar from '../../components/utils/window/TopBar';
import WindowBody from '../../components/utils/window/WindowBody';
import DockItem from '../../components/DockItem';
import './assets/firefox.scss';
import TopBarInteraction from '../../components/utils/window/TopBarInteraction';
import StartApp from '../../components/startMenu/StartApp';

export const FirefoxApp = () => {

    const toggle = () => {
        document.getElementsByClassName('FirefoxApp')[0].classList.add('clicked')
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementsByClassName('firefox')[0].classList.add('active');
        }, 500);
    };
    
    return (
        <DockItem id='firefox' class="FirefoxApp" title='Firefox' icon='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yeyushengfan258/Citrus-icon-theme/7fac80833a94baf4d4a9132ea9475c2b819b5827/src/scalable/apps/firefox.svg' onClick={toggle}/>
    )
};

export const FirefoxStartApp = () => {
    
    const toggle = () => {
        document.getElementsByClassName('StartMenuWrapper')[0].classList.remove('active');
        document.getElementsByClassName('Header')[0].classList.add('active');
        document.getElementsByClassName('DesktopBody')[0].classList.add('active');
        document.getElementsByClassName('FirefoxApp')[0].classList.add('clicked')
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementsByClassName('firefox')[0].classList.add('active');
        }, 500);
    };

    return (
        <StartApp key='firefox' icon='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yeyushengfan258/Citrus-icon-theme/7fac80833a94baf4d4a9132ea9475c2b819b5827/src/scalable/apps/firefox.svg' name='Firefox' onClick={toggle}/>
    )
}

export default function Firefox() {
    const [url, setUrl] = useState('');

    const isValidURL = (string) => {
        var res = string.match(
          /(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g
        );
        return res !== null;
    };

    const action = (e) => { // <- issue starts from here
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            var qry = e.target.value;
    
            if (isValidURL(qry)) {
              if (!qry.startsWith("http")) {
                qry = "https://" + qry;
              }
            } else {
              qry = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + qry + '&igu=1';
            }
    
            e.target.value = qry;
            setTimeout(() => {setUrl(qry)}, 500)
        }
    }

    function close(){
        document.getElementsByClassName('firefox')[0].classList.remove('active');
        document.getElementById('firefox').classList.remove('clicked');
        setTimeout(() => {setUrl('')}, 200);
    }

    function minimize(){
        document.getElementsByClassName('firefox')[0].classList.toggle('minimize');
    }

    function reload(){
        document.getElementById('iFrameFF').src = document.getElementById('iFrameFF').src;
    }

    return (
        <div className='FirefoxWindow'>   
                <div
                    className='Window firefox'
                    key={Math.random()}
                >
                    <TopBar title='Firefox' onDblClick={minimize}>
                        <div className='TabBarWrapper'>
                            <div className='TabBar'>
                                <div className='TabBarItem' style={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                                    <p>New Tab</p>
                                    <div className='CloseButton' onClick={close}>
                                        <i class="fa-regular fa-xmark"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className='TabBarItem' style={{ width: "100vw" }}>
                                    <div className='TabBarInteraction'>
                                        <i className="fa-regular fa-chevron-left"></i>
                                        <i className="fa-regular fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                        <i className="fa-regular fa-rotate-right" onClick={reload}></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <input className='TabSearch' type='text' spellCheck='false' placeholder='Search with Google or enter address' onKeyDown={action}/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='TopBarInteractionWrapper' style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                            <TopBarInteraction action='hide'/>
                            <TopBarInteraction action='minMax' onMinMax={minimize}/>
                            <TopBarInteraction action='close' onClose={close}/>
                        </div>
                    </TopBar>
                    <WindowBody>
                        <div className='Firefox'>
                            {url == '' ? <div className='welcomepage'>
                                <img src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yeyushengfan258/Citrus-icon-theme/7fac80833a94baf4d4a9132ea9475c2b819b5827/src/scalable/apps/firefox.svg' width='90px' height='90px'/>
                                <h1>Welcome to Firefox on BreezeOS</h1>
                                <p>Click the search bar on top to Google search or input URL address.</p>
                            </div> : ''}
                            <iframe id='iFrameFF' className='iFrameFF' src={url} title='New Tab' frameBorder='0'/>
                        </div>
                    </WindowBody>
                </div> 
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is fundamentally not allowed in React. In React, there are very few circumstances where you can grab a DOM element reference and *write* to properties (with some pretty rare exceptions, that aren't relevant here). React-owned DOM can only be modified via React's mechanisms, that is changing state and subsequently rendering JSX that you need for that given state.

This is a common mistake new developers to React make. It takes some time to fully grasp how to model problems like this in React, in a way that is declarative and not imperative.

Here you are editing the `classlist` of an HTML node. As soon as React re-renders (which happens on state change), then any imperative changes you made will be wiped instantly because they are not expressed in the JSX. Effectively, React doesn't even know they happened, and it won't make any effort to retain them. It will go about its business on a re-render writing to the DOM according to the JSX and the state it references at that given point in time.

Additionally, your components are also reaching out and modifying DOM nodes owned by *another* component. This breaks the entire point in react, as components are no longer encapsulated and portable.

You probably need to go from the beginning on the official React docs. Your code as it is currently doesn't show where `FirefoxStartApp` and `FirefoxApp` are actually used. Additionally, I strongly suspect that you are using the wrong tools for the job you are trying to achieve.

To change a class name, in the most basic case, you would do something like this:

```
const Toy = () => {
   const [active, setActive] = useState(false)

   return <div className={active ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => setActive(prev => !prev)}>Hello</div>
}
```

There's also no DOM element with the class `firefox`. There is `Firefox` but `getElementsByClassName` is case sensitive so that won't match.

To help more your question would need to be edited to show a wider context. Especially where `FirefoxApp` and `FirefoxStartApp` are mounted and used.